# The two definitions of a compact set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

1. In general, $A$ is compact if every open cover of $A$ contains a finite subcover of $A$.

   In $R$, $A$ is compact if it is closed and bounded.

The second is very easy to understand because I can easily come up with an example like $[0,1]$ which is both closed and bounded so it's compact.

However, I am very confused at definition (1) because I don't really understand what is meant by a cover and I don't understand how this is really related to a set being closed and bounded?

Could someone please explain what is the relationship between (1) and (2)?

Thank you.

Comment: It's a highly nontrivial theorem that (1) and (2) are equivalent for subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$, so you shouldn't expect some easy explanation.  Have you seen a proof of it?

Comment: @EricWofsey, No.

Comment: On the other hand, compactness is a generalization, in some sense, of finite sets. i.e., compact sets have many properties plausibles in finite sense.

Comment: @sinbadh , Why does the cover have to be open?

Comment: @EricWofsey, What is the difference between an open cover and just a cover?

Comment: A cover of X is a collection of sets V such that the X is a subset of the union of V.  An open cover means all the sets are open. If X is in R then the collection of intervals (x - 1/2, x+1/2) for x in X is an open cover of X.  If every open cover has a finite subcover this collect has a finite subcover and as each only 1 long, X is finite long.  I.e. bounded.  If X isn't closed then you can find a limit point not in X and you can have an infinite neighborhood containing points of X but any finite subcover of thes neighborhoods leave out points.  compact => closed, bounded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $X \subset R$

1) Compact => bounded.

I find it easy to just do this.  For every $x \in X$ let $V_x = (x-1/2, x + 1/2)$.  $V_x$ is open and $X \subset of \cup V_x$. So {$V_x$} is an open cover.  So it has a finite subcover.  So there is a lowest interval  and there is a greatest interval in the finite subcollection of intervals and X is bounded between them.

2) Compact => closed

Let X not be closed.  Then there is a limit point,y, of X that is not in X.  Let's let $V_n$ = {$x \in \mathbb R| |x - y| > 1/n$}.  As this covers all $\mathbb R$ except $y$ and $y \not \in X$ it covers X.  Take any finite subcover the is a maximum value of $n$ so $(y - 1/n, y + 1/n)$ is not covered by the finite subcover.  As $y$ was a limit point, $(y - 1/n, y + 1/n)$ contains points of X.  So the subcover doesn't cover X.  So X is not compact.

Unfortunately Closed and Bounded => compact is much harder.

But I hope I gave you a sense of the flavor of compact sets.

Comment: I understood the bounded point, but not sure about the closed point (2).

Comment: Well, consider the not closed X =  (0, 1).  Then 0 is limit point but 0 is not in X.  Consider: V_n = (1/n, 1).  These are open sets and the infinite number of them cover (0,1) so they are an (infinite) open cover.  Take a finite subset of them.  Then the is some maximum n is the finite collection so the finite collection only covers (1/n, 1) and (0, 1/n] is left uncovered.  So there is no finite subcover.  So X is not compact.

Comment: I always found the easiest way to show compact => bounded for $X \subset R$ was to consider the open cover $C = \{V_n \; : \; V_n = (-n , n), \; n \in \mathbb{N} \}.$  Since there is a finite subcover, there is a largest $n' \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $X$ is covered, hence $X$ is contained in an open ball of radius $n'.$

Comment: Merkh.  Very neat and clean.  I was going for something like that but that is very clean.  And universally applicable.  Of course this is in R.  Gets a bit more obtuse with general complete spaces.

Answer (score 2):

The definitions of open cover and finite subcover can be stated simply.  An open cover of $A$ is a collection of open sets in the underlying topology whose union includes all of $A$.  This definition of compactess says that if you have any open cover of any set $A$, you should be able to find a finite collection of sets in that cover that also cover $A$.  As an example, let $A=[0,1]$ and my collection of sets be $(\frac 1{2n-1},2), n \in \Bbb N \cup (\frac {-1}{1000},\frac 1{1000})$.  Every point in $[0,1]$ is in at least one of these sets, so it is a cover.  We can find a finite subcollection by requiring that $n \lt 1000$ in the first piece that also covers $[0,1]$.  To prove that $[0,1]$ is compact under this definition you would have to show that finding such a finite subcover was possible for any cover.  On the other hand, let $B=\Bbb R$.  We can cover $B$ with $(2n, 2n+2), n \in \Bbb Z$ but no finite subcollection covers $\Bbb R$, so $\Bbb R$ is not compact. The reason we specify an open cover is that we could cover $[0,1]$ with $[\frac 1{n+1}, \frac 1n] \cup \{0\}$ and not have a finite subcover. We want $[0,1]$ to be compact, so need to choose a definition that makes it so.

Comment: When talking about a cover i.e $\{V_{i}\}$, do the $V_{i}$ sets have to be inside each other?

Comment: No, they can be any collection as long as they cover.  In my examples they are not inside each other.  When you say open cover they all have to be open.

Answer (score 1):

The relationship between 1 and 2 is due to the fact that R has the least upper bound property (aka R is complete). The proof of the equivalency can be found pretty easily online. Baby Rudin contains the proof in the 2nd chapter when Cauchy sequences are introduced.

Answer (score 0):

The relation between the two exists in R^n only. The equivalence of the two conditions is given by Heine–Borel theorem. The proof is given nicely in S kumarsen's book named Topology of Metric Spaces. 
IN general topological space the 2nd definition is meaningless as there is no notion of boundedness.